# show caret on readonly html input

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, progressive-web-apps, text-cursor

I am creating a calculator, that I want to use on browser and mobile as progressive web app. I created my own input buttons and don't want to see the virtual keyboard on mobile. For that reason I am using the attribute `readonly` on the `input`.

I want to show the cursor, so the user knows, where the number or operator will be inserted.

Unfortunately a readonly input shows the cursor only in firefox mobile, not in chrome mobile. So I cannot rely on the built in cursor.

I need a way to show the cursor for the input field, while the virtual keyboard is not opened, when clicking into the input field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the issue, I implemented my own caret. I created a div with 1px width and proper height. The `#caret` is positioned relatively to the `.input-group`.

To make it easy, I use a monospaced font on the input. So every character has same width. Then I just listen for any event on the input and update the position of the caret accordingly. `text-shadow` and transparent `color` make the original caret invisible on firefox mobile.

My input field is aligned to the right.

*Updated*
https://jsfiddle.net/9fr46y2w/3/

*HTML*

```
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" id="input" onclick="showCaret(this);">
  <div id="caret"></div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
#input {
  color: transparent;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 36px;
  height: 48px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 #yourTextColor;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-group {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

#caret {
  background: white;
  color: transparent;
  height: 41px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  right:0;
  width: 1px;

  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: blink;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  from {
    opacity: 1; 
  }

  49.9% {
      opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  99.9% {
      opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
 }
```

*JavaScript*

```
function showCaret(input) {
  let widthSizeRatio = 21.6/36;
  let charWidth = widthSizeRatio * 36;
  let length = input.value.length;
  let cur = input.selectionStart;

  document.getElementById("caret").style.right = Math.floor((length - cur) * charWidth) + "px";
}
```

Comment: One small detail I noticed with this implementation: The animation is not reset after changing position. So when clicking at the right timing the cursor seems to appear later, because it is hidden for 500ms. So a little improvement would be to reset the animation upon changing the position.